# C#: Increase timeout for socket async receive

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using tcp socket and trying to `socket.ReceiveAsync()` on it. Sometimes I receive

> SocketError.TimedOut (WSAETIMEDOUT 10060)

when remote host is unavailable for some time. I would like to increase the timeout for this. As far as I understood changing `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` doesn't make sense since it is only applied to sync `Receive()` call.
How can I increase timeout for `ReceiveAsync()`?

Comment: The server should be running before the client is started.  There is no retry in the client for a connection.  So increasing the timeout will not solve issue.  You said you sometimes get the timeout.  What do you do to fix the issue.?  Do you just try again?

Comment: No, I need just to have more time to keep the connection open, and the remote host will be up again soon. This is kind of for testing purpose.

Comment: It won't work because the connection only attempted once.  You must have enough time in code to start server before trying the connection.

Comment: If the host is not up then you may want to keep pining the host until it is up and then try to connect.

Comment: The host is up at the beginning and the connection is established. Then host goes down for a while and at this time I receive SocketError.TimedOut. I guess it happens in about 20 seconds. I think that there were not ACK to some packet sent towards host. I am just wondering if I can increase the time before I can receive this SocketError.TimedOut? The host will be up again soon.

Comment: There are three different cases that could be occurring. 1) The host broke the connection.  Then you need to reconnect.  2) The host sent off-line and received message and will respond.3) The host went off-line and did not get the message and you need to resend.  The best solution is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get correct results.

Comment: I guess there is point 3 happening here. The packet is sent to host, but was not even acknowledged since host is offline. Then there is WSAENETRESET error on every send and even after remote host is up again.
Is there any way to recover the very same socket after WSAENETRESET happens? Or control TCP re-transmission timeouts?

Comment: No.  Once a connection is broken you have to reconnect.  Check from a cmd.exe window : > netstat -a.  Check the state of the connection.  The connection has to be closed before you can reconnect.  When a server goes down sometimes a connection is left in a 'half open half close state' and you cannot reconnect without disposing the old connection.

Comment: I've actually achieved what I wanted by increasing tcpmaxdataretransmissions parameter in TCP in registry. But this applies for all network connection on his machine. I just wonder if there is any way to modify this for certain connection? Or this is global network settings and can't be changed for just one connection?

Comment: How large did you make the parameter?  Usually tcp retries ~3 times at 5 seconds intervals.  So this looks like a possible hardware issue.  I would use PING with a large count and large size (see ping/?) and make sure the results look good (no errors, dropped packets, or long delays).